# Unity Time.time not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, unityscript

I have spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out, but I cannot. I am making a very very simple drag racer on Unity3d(2D). Just a sensor to be broken to start a timer and a couple incremental times along the way. Ive got the colliders working fine and i can keep track of which increment I am passing with a DebugLog; but, I cannot get the timer to work correctly.

```
static function Timer(Cone : String){

if(Cone == "StageBeamBroken" ){

    var StartTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
}

Debug.Log(Cone + ": " + ( Time.realtimeSinceStartup - StartTime));}
```

basically the Timer(probably poorly named) function is supposed to take in a String(name of the increment) and either start the timer then print(DebugLog) out the time each time another increment is collided with.

There are no compiler errors.

The output is something like this:

```
StageBeamBroken: 2.6E-06
FirstIncrement: 4.89
SecondIncrement: 6.26
Final Increment: 7.26
```

As you can see the first time it runs, when it sees "StageBeamBroken" the (Time.time-StartTime) works perfectly and outputs 0(basically). But, then it jumps ahead to (what seems like) the real run time since Startup without subtracting StartTime( the Second increment should be substantially less than 2 seconds. If I sit, without breaking the start beam for say 40 seconds, 40 seconds will be added to the Second Increment... Please help!

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `StartTime` variable outside the `Timer(String)` function, because your programm simply getting `StartTime` only once, when `Cone == "StageBeamBroken"`. And right after function is complete value of `StartTime` is getting lost.

Comment: Got it Thanks!

Add

Static var StartTime : float; 

Outside of Timer(String)

Static is the key I was missing